# Ubuntu kernels on 20.04 on Nvidia-based system

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, nvidia

I am running 20.04 LTS on an HP X360. When I start the machine the grub splash page needs me to go to kernel 5.3.0-64 generic in order to get further. This despite having received notification of two new kernels which I duly got Ubuntu to install.

To be a bit more precise: if I use the default kernel (5.4.0-53) then I get as far as the user identification page, the cursor appears near the bottom right of the screen and freezes if I use either more recent versions. If I use 5.4.0-53 I just get a blank screen.

Going back to 5.3.0-64 frees everything up.

FWIW I am running Metacity as UI and an NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX as graphics engine

Are there issues with later kernels? If so what can I/should I do about the situation? Is removal of later kernels possible/recommended?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of `nvidia-driver-*` do you use? Current official version is 455, so you shall run `apt-cache policy nvidia-driver-455` and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 20.04 based Mint 20 now, and wanted to install version 455, but it throws some errors, so I'm using 450 still.

Comment: Thanks @LinuxSecurityFreak . Interestingly Software Update tells me that I am running a manually installed driver (doesn't say quite what) and the radio buttons won't let me deselect it and use another driver. I don't recall loading a manually installed driver :-) Any suggestions how I might get round it?

Comment: Tried to install 455 as per instructions [at linuxconfig.org](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux) ...made no difference except that latest version just goes no further than the initial page showing "HP" and "Ubuntu"

Comment: Also found that X11 server could be made to work, but 440 gives better results

Comment: It now works with 5.4.0-53